# Static casting an __int128 to double

Tags: c++, assembly, arm64, intrinsics

I am trying a small bit of code to convert an __int128 to a double, which is needed by my computations, neglecting precision issues, I only need an approximate value from that.
I am using an ARM Cortex-A53 (single core baremetal) to run my computations.

A performance hit happens only in this line of code

```
__int128 testInt;
double testDbl = static_cast<double>(testInt);
```

Drilling down the problem, I've removed all the code leaving only this in a for-loop and what I see is that only that is taking around 6us on the ARM. By having a look at the assembly code, a suspicious `bl __floattidf` is pointing me towards the FPU but I am compiling that using aarch64. Aarch64 assures that the FPU is enabled by default. Actually, the only used flag is the `-mcpu=cortex-a53` to target the specific CPU in use.

What I also experiment is that something fishy is also happening on my PC side (Intel Core i7-10750H) where that instruction alone is also taking more time than multiplications or divisions.

I have no other clues but I would like to understand:

- What am I missing about that `static_cast`?
- How can I improve, without changing the need for the `__int128`/`double` conversion?

Comment: Maybe posting a snippet of the tested minimal code and the relative generated assembly would help.

Comment: There's no HW support for `__int128` -> double conversion, so the compiler has to use multiple instructions; not at all surprising that code to handle the general case exactly is slow.  (In the libgcc function that converts a tetra-int to a double-float, ti to df.)  The "instruction" you're looking at is a function call, ARM64 `bl` is branch-with-link.  https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libgcc/soft-fp/floattidf.c.html is a generic version of the C source which uses macros.

Comment: `objdump -drwC -Mintel /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/libgcc.a` is one way to see the asm that actually runs; it involves a bit-scan for the highest set bit (x86 `bsr`), or actually highest significant bit in a signed number so highest 0 if negative. And a shift to normalize it.  IDK if it would work to bit-scan your int128 and right shift it so the 64 most significant bits are in an `int64_t`, and then convert that and multiply by a power of 2 to fix up the FP exponent.  Or if that's what the library function is already doing.

Comment: Do you know anything about the range of your number?  Is it always > INT64_MAX (so your bit-scan for the most-significant could only look at that half)?  Is it always non-negative, so you don't need to maybe scan for the highest 0?  If so, you could maybe optimize for that special case.  If your number is always small enough to fit in an `int64_t`, that would obviously be much faster.  IDK if the libgcc version takes a lot of extra work to produce a "correctly rounded" result, with error < 0.5ulp, as opposed to just truncating or something.

Comment: The `bl __floattidf` means that the code is essentially `double testDbl = __floattidf(testsInt)`. If you are using clang, you can find it's implementation here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/floattidf.c

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: If you don't care that much about the rounding, what about simply doing everything in floating point? Convert the high and low halves of `testInt` as 64-bit integers to `double`, FP multiply the high half by 2**64, and FP add the low half?  [This](https://godbolt.org/z/P3zod7EP8) looks pretty efficient.  Should get you much closer to 6 ns than 6 us.  Also [vectorizes pretty good](https://godbolt.org/z/Tx7TT4j4v) if you have to process a whole array of them.

Comment: Though if I'm not mistaken, the load and shuffle in the vectorized version could be done in one instruction as `ld2 { v3.2d, v4.2d }, [x9], #32`.